# Regex group from within custom grok pattern

Tags: logstash, grok

I'm trying to create custom grok patterns to extract various data using logstash and am wracking my brain getting the syntax correct to pull the regex group 1 equivalent from my log rows.  I've looked at a ton of threads on this over the past 2 days, but nothing's out there that fits my example, and none of the canned grok patterns seem like they will pull the value I need.

3 example log file rows look similar to this (with abbreviated data for the examples):

```
2022-04-07 12:52:06,184:INFO   :Thread-70_SCHEDULE.0001: MsgID=63759111848731967
2022-04-07 07:23:39,876:INFO   :Thread-53_OrderInterfaceIntServer: MsgID=21316889724753182|
07:23:40,482 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-20) 2022-04-07 07:23:40,482:ERROR
```

I want to create a custom grok pattern called SERVICE that extracts a pattern match using a regex match string:

```
Thread-[0-9]{2}_(.*?)\:
```

that for the 3 rows would return:

- SCHEDULE.0001
- OrderInterfaceIntServer
- ""

In the log:

- SERVICE will always be prefixed by "Thread-xx_" where xx = 2-digit number followed by underscore.  Some logs may not have this pattern at all (like row 3).  In that case, no match.
- SERVICE is always followed by a colon

In grok, I can define this in 2 ways:

```
SERVICE Thread-[0-9]{2}_(.*?)\:
or as a field using (?<service>Thread-[0-9]{2}_(.*?)\:)
```

however, for row 1, I get the response value of:

```
{
  "service": [
    [
      "Thread-70_SCHEDULE.0001:"
    ]
  ]
}
```

What I want is:

```
{
  "service": [
    [
      "SCHEDULE.0001"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Which is the equivalent of the regex group 1 response.  I can't figure out how to manage the grok patterns to get the result I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to include all of the pattern in the capture group. You can use

```
grok { match => { "message" => "Thread-[0-9]{2}_(?<service>.*?):" } }
```

That will result in

```
   "service" => "SCHEDULE.0001",

   "service" => "OrderInterfaceIntServer",
```

and a "_grokparsefailure" tag on the third event.